# Auto upload to Onedrive- Best quality with wi-fi?

Tags: onedrive, photos, uploading

In settings => applications => photos+camera => Auto upload-Onedrive, I get to choose:

- Don't upload
- Good quality (may use data plan)
- Best quality (needs Wi-Fi)

I have a virtually-unlimited data plan, so I never bother with Wi-Fi. Is there a way to set to "Best quality using data plan"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you already be suspecting, that is not possible. The operating system is trying to protect people from themselves and do not allow people who may not have a good data plan chew through it too quickly.

Comment: I suspected as much. With Data Sense, WP should be better aware of my actual plan, so here hoping for better bandwidth usage decisions out of it.

Comment: In all reality, WP operating system is very immature in a lot of nooks and crannies. This would be a great place to allow for more advanced options.

Comment: Not fixed in 8.1 either. Eventually I re-enabled Wi-Fi, and disabled its announcments of any network I happen to walk/drive near. So now pictures gets uploaded automatically when I'm at home /work /a few other familiar places, which is not bad - though I'd really rather just use the data plan.